# What are the steps to export a VM using the vmware vcenter 7 rest api

Tags: api, rest, export, vmware, vcenter

I'm attempting to build some custom automation to handle the import / export of VM's to / from an on-prem vmware cluster.

So far I have authenticated the rest api, can get a VM's info, but I cannot work out how to approach exporting the selected VM.

I believe I'll need to create a download session & iterate through its files, saving them to disk one by one whilst keeping the download session alive, but the documentation seems to skirt around the concept of exporting a VM and focus predominantly on deploying.

Does anyone have an example / list of steps required to achieve exporting a VM via the Rest API?

Answer (score 1):

As of 7.0U2, that functionality doesn't exist in the vSphere Automation (REST) API. Here are the top level VM functions: [link](https://developer.vmware.com/docs/vsphere-automation/latest/vcenter/vcenter/VM/)

If you're open to using the vSphere Web Services (SOAP) API, there's an `exportVM` function available: [link](https://vdc-download.vmware.com/vmwb-repository/dcr-public/8946c1b6-2861-4c12-a45f-f14ae0d3b1b9/a5b8094c-c222-4307-9399-3b606a04af55/vim.VirtualMachine.html#exportVm)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to automate VMs import/export I recommend to use OVF Tool / PowerCLI.
I leave you a KB with example https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1038709